# CSV Link from react-csv exporting incomplete data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, export-to-csv

I'm using CSV Link from react-csv to export CSV data in a table with selectable rows. There is a problem in the way the data is getting exported. When I select 3 rows, for example, it's omitting the last row from the resulting CSV file that is outputted. If I select 4 rows, it will only export 3 rows the first time, and so on. If I hit the export button a second time, the complete set of rows will get exported.

Here is how I'm passing data to the CSV Link component:

```
<CSVLink
 data={getExportTransactionRows(t.transactions)}
 headers={getExportTransactionHeaders(t)}
 filename={t.companyName}
>
```

Here is the `getExportTransactionRows` function that returns the rows:

```
  const getExportTransactionRows = (transactions) => {
    let trans = transactions.filter((t) => t.selected === true);
    if (trans?.length === 0) trans = transactions;
    return trans;
  };
```

Comment: I think the reason why you just keep exporting the previous row is that your `getExportTransactionRows(t.transactions)s` don't change value right away when you selected row. You can declare a variable that saves your export data. Then in your select event and change that variable when you selected. Passing it into CSVLink

Comment: You're right! The event handler for the select event wasn't causing a rerender. The first export was causing a rerender, which was then getting picked up by the second export. I can select your response as the correct answer if you submit an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I will submit my answer. Glad that I can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason why you just keep exporting the previous row is that your getExportTransactionRows(t.transactions)s don't change value right away when you selected row. You can declare a variable that saves your export data. Then in your select event and change that variable when you selected. Passing it into CSVLink